# Entity Framework Core: efficient database update

Tags: entity-framework-core, updates, insert-update

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app using Entity Framework Core to update a database. But I need some advice to know if I am using the good way to update a given table.

Let's say I have a table `TableState` with three columns: `ID`, `DESCRIPTION` and `STATE` (`ID` is the primary key), and below is its associated entity class called `TableState`:

```
public class TableState
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Given a list of `TableState` objects, I need to update efficiently the table.

The update is peculiar because for each `TableState` object within the list:

- if I find an associated record within the table (using the primary key `ID`), I need to update the record
- if I do not find it within the table, I need to insert it into the database
- finally if it exists in the database, but not within the list, I need to update the `State` column to INACTIVE

Here is the algorithm I implemented and I want some feedback to know if it can be improved:

```
public void UpdateTableState (List<TableState> inputs)
{
      var currentTableStates = Context.Set<TableSet>().ToList();            

      // I retrieve all records in the database
      // One way to detect records to add or update
      foreach (TableState input in inputs)
      {
            var foundTableState = currentTableState.FirstOrDefault(ts => ts.ID == input.Id);

            // The input does not exist in DB, so it must be added
            if (foundTableState == null) 
            {
                Context.Set<TableSet>().Add(foundTableState);
            }
            else
            {
                foundTableState.Description = input.Description;
                foundTableState.State = "Active";
            }
      }

      // Second way to detect records to delete (set its State field to INACTIVE)
      foreach (TableState currentTableState in currentTableStates )
      {
            var foundInList = inputs.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == currentTableState.Id);

            // The input does not exist in DB, so it must be added
            if (foundTableState == null) 
            {
                  Context.Set<TableState>.Remove(currentTableState);
            }
      }
}
```

If someone finds a better way to update the table, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: With vanilla EF Core such operation is inefficient. If you are interested I can prepare sample with EF Core extension, which uses MERGE operator for such case.

Comment: If input doesn't exist it will not have any id in the property? So why dont you do straight insert which dont have id. FYI bringing all the data to memory will be an issue if you have thousands of data

Comment: Hi @SvyatoslavDanyliv, thank you for your time and I am interested in your sample with EF Core if it is possible. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by EF Core extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (disclaimer: I'm one of the creators)

```cs
public void UpdateTableState (List<TableState> inputs)
{
      Context.Set<TableSet>()
        .Merge()
        .Using(inputs)
        .OnTargetKey()
        .UpdateWhenMatched((t, s) => new TableState { Description = s.Description, State = "Active" })
        .InsertWhenNotMatched()
        .UpdateWhenNotMatchedBySource(s => new TableState { State = "Inactive" })
        .Merge();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of brining the entire collection to memory try limiting by your input data.

```
var ids = inputs.Select(x => x.Id);
var insert = inputs.Where(x=>Id==null || Id == 0).ToList() //This are data need be inserted

//This will fetch the items which exist in the table so this can be updated
var foundinTable = Context.Set<TableSet>()
                                .Where(x=> ids.Contains(x.Id)
                                .ToList();

var tobeInserted = foundIntable.Where(x> !ids.Contains(x.Id).ToList()
```

This has reduces our Dbset to return only related data. Now you iteraite over it and update it.

Comment: Hi and thanks you for your answer, in fact, if the ID property are pre-generated by an third-party program.

Comment: @J.Doe In that case get the records which are in db like in the answer rest of the items are you need to insert

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thank you for your response.

@Eldho, your code could be right, but I need to detect also the records in DB which do not exist in the input collection. But thank you anyway, I will try to avoid bringing the entire DB table in memory before comparing. But I think it is not possible because:

1. If a record in DB does not exist in the input: I need to update its State column to INACTIVE
2. Otherwise I need to update it according to its associated input
3. Every input which do not exist in DB (their ID = 0) I need to add them into DB.

Thank you

Comment: Remove this comment. It is not answer.